# Big Beam LVL or Glu Lam load capacity to support a gymnast

Tags: structural-engineering, beam

I need help knowing if I am selecting the correct wood beam.

The load will be all near the center and a 250 pound man will be doing pull ups on it. I would estimate a 1,000 pound dynamic load to be safe.

I am looking at a 3.5in x 12 in x 20ft Big Beam (LP makes it, it's an LVL). It will only be supported at the ends.

How can I calculate the correct beam size? Thanks.

Comment: What is the allowable or desired deflection?

Answer (score 1):

If you can approximate it as isotropic material, then you can use Euler beam theory to find the stress and compare it to the yield stress:

$ \sigma = My/I$

- $ \sigma $ = normal stress
- $ y $ = distance from neutral plane (midplane of symmetric section
  beam). Maximum stress occurs at the outside edge so use $y=h/2$ where $h$ is the height of the beam (12 in).
- $ I $ = 2nd moment of area of the section about the axis perpendicular to y and also in the plane of the section. For a rectangular section, $I=b h^3/12$. $b$ is the width of the beam. For other shapes like I-beam, see Google.
- $ M $ is the bending moment. For a simply-supported beam (is it simply supported?) with point load at the center, the bending moment at the center (where it's maximum), is $ M = FL/4 $. $F$=load (1000 lb_f) and $L$ = length (20 ft).

Beware that there might be other failure modes too.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I plugged in the numbers and get .

Comment: Something's missing from your comment.

Comment: What are you suggesting to limit the bending stress too? NDS has free documents available with adjustment factors and formulas that are used for Structural design.

Answer (score 0):

Force, P = 1000 lbs

Beam Span, L = 20'

Max. Moment, M = PL/4 = 1000(20)/4 = 5000 lb-ft

Shear, V = P/2 = 1000/2 = 500 lbs

According to the table below, both of your choices are capable of handling the load.

**LVL 2650Fb-1.9E Technical Guide**

[image]

**24F Douglas-Fir Design Table**

[image]